# Removing many objects from Three.js scene slow

Tags: javascript, three.js

We deal with large Three.js scenes with many individual objects. It is easy to end up with scene having 25k to 50k `Object3D` instances. Yes, this is a lot, but we currently don't see an easy way to lower this number. Clearing such a scene by removing all objects takes usually about two minutes. This is the case for both removing each element individually with `scene.remove(element);` and for collecting all elements first and calling `scene.remove(element1, element2, ...);`. We also tried replacing the complete scene instance, but to no avail: it was still slow.

We saw some differences between different graphics cards and suspect this has to do with using a lot of buffer geometries that presumably would need to be removed from the graphics card (which then would have some influence on performance).

Since the browser is blocking during object removal, the website becomes unusable for this period of time. Do you see any way of improving object removal performance or make it non-blocking (without `setTimeout()` for removing individual elements)?

This shows the problem in a simplified fashion (using 50k cubes, removed after first frame, but some of our objects are much more complex): http://jsfiddle.net/ua2mg5ty/

Comment: Yikes. Perhaps you should be using `InstancedBufferGeometry`. See, for example, [this](http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_buffergeometry_instancing.html) and [this](http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_buffergeometry_instancing_dynamic.html).

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! If I am not mistaken, using `InstanceBufferGeometry` implies that individual object instances would be similar. We display many big neurons that are all very different from each other. They are currently based on `LineSegments` using regular `Geometry` instances. I suppose I could use `InstanceBufferGeometry` to store only a single line segment and use an offset array to instance individual line segments at the correct position. Does this make sense?

Comment: Maybe. Or use `BufferGeometry`. Avoid regular geometry. Be careful to call `dispose()` when removing objects.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, `InstanceBufferGeometry` turned out to work nicely for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try mesh merge and remove a single mesh.

http://jsfiddle.net/2t8j5caj/

Removal time: 0.13500000000021828ms, Render time: 3.6000000000012733ms

```
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(singleGeometry, material);
for (var i = 0; i < nCubes; i++) {
  var box = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
  var cube = new THREE.Mesh(box);
  cube.position.x = (Math.random() - 0.5) * 5;
  cube.position.y = (Math.random() - 0.5) * 5;
  cube.position.z = (Math.random() - 0.5) * 5;
  cube.scale.set((Math.random() - 1 * cubeSize), (Math.random() - 1 * cubeSize), (Math.random() - 1 * cubeSize))
  cube.updateMatrix();

  singleGeometry.merge(cube.geometry, cube.matrix);
}
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(singleGeometry, material);
scene.add(mesh);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is another good suggestion. I have yet to find out if this works in my use-case: Logical objects (neurons in my case) contain of multiple meshes that I want to show/hide individually and apply different shaders to and have different mouse picking behavior. I would probably loose all this when merging all meshes within one logical object.

Comment: Cheers. Possibly, you can apply shaders to specific faces in the mesh before merge, and modify the specific material for showing/hiding specific faces. Ray picking is already face based.  Think of the mesh as collections of faces rather than discrete mesh objects. The latter is preferable- it feels like freedom, but JS simply can't handle a set that large in its single thread. Also remember that faces and vertexes are class objects which can be given properties that the Three devs did not intend. Three is prototype class based. Extending a Three class properly will not taint class integrity.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to accept this answer. I ended up not doing what you suggested, but your answer as well as WestLangley's comments on my question lead me in the right direction: I now construct `InstanceBufferGeometry` objects and shaders manually, which results in only a few milliseconds for removal.

Comment: I think it's important to state that wrapping webGL in JavaScript brings some trade offs, and careful consideration of performance limitations need to be weighed against the requirements of each project undertaken. I am glad you found an alternative that worked!